# javascript massive field get elements

Tags: javascript, massive

i have that code  here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
 #game {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    background: orangered;
}

.block {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
  </style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="game"></div>
 <script>
    var kvadratiki = [];
    pole();
    var i;
    var j;
    function pole() {
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        kvadratiki[i]=[];
        for (var j=0; j<3; j++) {
            kvadratiki[i][j] = document.getElementById('game').innerHTML+='<div class="block"></div>';
        };  

    };
};

var hod = 0;

    document.getElementById('game').onclick = function(event){
        console.log(event);
        if (event.target.className == 'block'){
            if (hod%2==0) {
                event.target.innerHTML = 'x';
            }
            else {
                event.target.innerHTML = '0';
            }
            hod++;
            checkWinner();
        }
    }
var n;
var m;

function checkWinner(){
        var block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
        for (var n=0; n<i; n++) {
            for (var m=0; m<j; m++) {
                if (kvadratiki[n][m] == kvadratiki[n+1][m+1] && 'x') {
                    alert('X WINS')
                } 
            }
        }
};

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its fieldd 3x3, when you click it - you put 'x' or '0' in one of blocks
I want to type code that  allows me to check, if i have all 'x' or '0' in row or column or in diagonal, for example field 3x3 - field ij:

```
00 01 02
10 11 12
20 21 22
```

I cant understand how to get elements like :

```
 [i][j],[i+1][j+1]  - diagonal
[i][j], [i][j+1] -row
[i][j], [i+1][j] -column
```

I want to set alert if 00, 11,22 - have 'x' 
and if 00 01 02 - as well
and 00 10 20 - as well

Comment: you can make a for loop that will check after every move if the condition of winning is matched or not and it can return true and false accordingly.

Comment: here is planker, can you show me example ? https://plnkr.co/edit/yweGWtfJwEeOkot5ejsW?p=preview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dtic+tac+toe